# Declare a global variable in JMeter property file

Tags: jmeter

I have a custom JMeter property file with some config of each thread group, and I read them by `__P` function. The example as following:

[image: Property file screen shot]

I have user count for each thread group. How can I set a global variable and point all group number to this number?

Answer (score 0):

You can copy property value in [JSR223 component](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_PostProcessor) using `props`:

```
props.put("group1.usercount",props.get("globle.usercount"));
```